# Shift from Java to c++

Tags: java, c++

I have been developing applications based on C# (.net) and Java (J2EE) for the last 3 years.

But now I feel, Java, C# makes you lame (from learning point of view) and you can develop your apps quickly but you fail to understand the basic underlying concepts of programming.

So, I am trying to learn C++, but I find it a little "confusing" due to pointer, multiple inheritance, some conventions and other concepts of C++ which don't exist in Java. So, what do you guys suggest? How should I feel about it?

Thanks

PS: I am a student, so have all the time in the world and actually shift.

Comment: You don't know the underlying concepts of programming? ...Where did you learn to code Java and C# from? What books? They aren't worth there salt if they didn't teach that alongside the programming concepts, hell, it's the first thing I learnt, even before programming; the fetch-execute cycle, pointers... And this was for Java!

Comment: If you really want to learn about how your code gets compiled, and whats happening on a lower level, I suggest assembly. To be honest it's really not as hard as it seems once you get into it, and you'll gain a ton of insight as to what's happening with your code once it's compiled (stack frame, etc).

Comment: Pick a  c++ open source project and read it's entire source code. But I also warn that shallow knowledge in multiple platform is not better than deep knowledge in VM platform (and language).

Comment: Well you should first be assertive about your knowledge in object oriented programming. For that, either Java or C# are easier to practice. After that, if you want to use a more powerful language, which lets you craft anything in any way you want, learn C++.

Comment: Ok an opinion from another student who had been coding java for almost 3 years, i wasted so much time asking good referecne etc to jump to C++ considering you know java. Answer: DONT do that, just pick up a good C++ book ans start over, if oyu know java you can skim through many sections pretty fast. I say go with C++ Primer 5th Edition and you'll already be done with few chapters in a single day, just go through a proper C++ book, and prior java knowledge will help you move faster on many sections. I did this and it has helped a hell lot, previously i wasted time looking for transition books.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In my opinion, you should learn C first in order to properly understand the base upon which C++ is built. Pick up a copy of "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie, widely considered the best reference on the language, and start reading through it. Once you fully understand C, you'll have the low-level base you need.

Comment: Continuing along this theme, learn assembly language first so you can understand what the C compiler is doing. The continue with learning C++.

Comment: I totally agree. Learning calling conventions and how functions actually work really helped me understand how the C language works as a whole.

Comment: The inventor of the C++ language would disagree with you - his words "If you want to learn C++, learn C++".

Comment: No, everyone knows you should wire wrap your own ALU out of raw 7400 ICs first. You can't say you know anything until the clock speed of your CPU is tied to how fast to you can press the STEP button on your breadboard. Do it right, get back to basics.

Comment: @Neil, he may disagree with me, but just because he invented the language doesn't mean he's right on that one. C has had an influence on C++ in so many ways, the C-reference in the name being only one of them. C is a smaller language that in many ways gives more insight into the hardware than C++ does, without fiddling with such higher-level things as exceptions and classes. In this instance, learning C and gaining all of the low-level experience from it is an excellent starting point to learning other imperative languages.

Comment: @Greg: continuing along this theme, learn your processor's micro-code before you learn assembly, so that you can understand what the CPU is doing. For that matter, it's hard to credit that anyone can write a decent Java program if they can't lay out the circuits on a modern processor ;-p

Comment: @avpx: since there is nothing that C89 does that C++ doesn't, I don't see what principles you can learn from C that you can't from learning C++ thoroughly. Really it's a "quality of implementation" issue for textbooks in each of the two languages. K&R does take a pretty low-level approach, it'd be interesting to know whether there's a C++ text which starts in the same vein, thus providing the same benefits for a C++ programmer who has no pressing need to write C89. TC++PL is I think not quite so nuts and bolts, although I don't have a copy of K&R to hand to refresh my memory.

Comment: @avpx I suspect that BS knows far more about C than you ever will. Did you know for example that his C++ compiler was used to test all the C code in K&R 2nd ed? Sorry, I'll take his opinion over yours on this one.

Comment: @Neil: *than you or I ever will.

Comment: @Neil, Steve: If you want to learn C++, study C++.  Yes.  But zengr doesn't want to learn C++.  zengr wants to learn how memory management and virtual functions work, and is thinking of using C++ to learn that.  It is for that goal (and not for learning C++) that learning C is suggested.

Comment: I read his question as him wanting to learn how to be a good programmer, and thinking of using C++ to learn that.  In which case, learning C just to understand pointers is a complete waste of time.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: +1 to your comment, that's exactly it. Programming languages are not inherently high- or low- level, they just different bunches of abstractions, and C's choices are no more basic or fundamental than any others; they still have to be emulated by many underlying layers. C certainly has fewer fundamental features than C++, but compare with a language like Scheme in which almost every facility is built on lambdas. Now *that's* minimal! And yet would we call it low-level? Really all this about is out-dated/irrelevant prejudices about "performance".

Answer (score 9):

C++ is no more "basic and underlying" than any other modern programming language. It has a model of a computer (a flat memory address space), but the OS and CPU merely simulates that model using many layers of caching and paging, so it's not "real". The result is that the same operation may sometimes take 1000s of times longer to complete than at other times.

Also modern C++ has lots of powerful abstractions that have no more direct relationship with how a computer works than do the abstractions provided in Java and C#. The OP mentions multiple inheritance - clearly no more elemental than inheritance in other OO languages. Many other features of C++ omitted from Java are high-level abstractions (or allow you to build them) and so in some ways Java is the more low-level language. In Java the meaning of operator symbols is always the same, whereas in C++ a simple `==` might build an object that will later be used to generate a SQL expression instead of being executed in-process.

The JVM and CLR runtimes are (almost certainly) written in C and/or C++, so in that sense obviously they happen to form layers today. But at the C/C++ layer you will still be working in an abstraction that is not "how the machine really works", so you'll really just be learning a different set of abstractions, rather than "reality". And an OS (or indeed a hardware chip) can be designed specifically so that JVM or CLR like runtimes are the native low-level layer of the system; on such a system it would be the C/C++ runtime that would require a "high-level" (expensive) emulation layer in order to work.

So it is probably not worth trying to learn how to program in "reality". No one really does that these days; it's a waste of time. You're better off learning about how programming abstractions help you to write correct programs. If a language makes life difficult for you, that doesn't prove you're doing the "real thing". It just means you picked the wrong language for what you're trying to do.

Comment: I tend to disagree with this. I feel that C++, although modern and high-level, can indeed be used as a learning tool for learning about things on a low_er_ level than Java or C#.

Comment: It's true that C++ is far from the silicon, in the sense that you could say the same about C, or about x86 or ARM assembler. I'm not certain how important that sense is, though. It could well be that what many people consider "fundamental" in fact is now completely out of date and irrelevant, or it could be that thinking in the C-style memory model does actually offer some good insights that Java doesn't.

Comment: Assembler and C don't have generic programming, polymorphic method dispatch, exceptions, operator overloading, constructors/destructors etc. So C++ is way more high-level than C, and those are the good parts of C++. The "old fashioned" part of C++ (the pointers that have the power to trash anything else in the address space) is the really bad part; it's perhaps worth understanding if only to get across the notion of what a poor choice of abstraction it makes for general programming.

Comment: Sure, if you believe that pointers are a useless abstraction which is in no sense fundamental, then the way to learn "important computing concepts" (if you already know Java and C#) is probably to learn Lisp, ML or Haskell. Actually, JITs currently do translate your Java code to a model which uses that pointer-based abstraction, though, and the Java-level abstraction *does* leak something from the C/assembler level (as well as things from the micro-code level), especially when it comes to performance. Hence, it may be useful to learn one of C, C++, or a common assembler.

Comment: Pointers are only fundamental if the machine really has a flat address space. Some machines do, some machines don't. It's quite possible that more and more machines in the future will have hardware support for fine-grained segregation of memory blocks and maybe GC as well. And (as I say in my answer) in user (as opposed to kernel) code, even in C the dereferences `*p` and `*(p + 1)` may differ in completion time by many orders of magnitude, because the flat memory space is actually itself another abstraction being simulated by the machine and OS, rather than being "real" or "fundamental".

Comment: It's true though that the higher-level "idiomatic" C++ stuff isn't useful for improving your understanding of what the JIT does and hence why your Java program behaves as it does. C would be better, as a "portable assembler" with fewer irrelevant distractions. C++ might be useful for understanding how the Java language was designed, in particular what *wasn't* taken from C++ (eg. concrete MI), and what was partly taken from C++ (eg. generics).

Comment: @Daniel: right, but it doesn't matter whether that abstraction is "fundamental" or not, provided it's useful. *If the JIT is using it*, which currently it is, then understanding it will yield at least some insights into the behaviour of the code produced by the JIT. Whether it's worth the effort, I don't know - certainly Joel Spolsky doesn't like Java programmers who don't understand pointers, but I'm not Joel Spolsky and anyway I've had very little professional contact with programmers who don't understand pointers.

Comment: I totally agree about the "useful" part. I'm just suspicious of assuming that just because the layer below in my tool chain is implemented to target some other abstraction, therefore that abstraction is more fundamental. It could just as easily be a painful diversion that has to be taken for historical reasons, and it would be much better if my abstractions were more directly supported by the machine. This is the present situation for Java programmers: their concepts are translated into C concepts to please the OS/CPU combo, which thinks its being helpful by working to simulate flat memory.

Comment: I think that for as long as Java contains NullPointerException, it's not just the JITs fault if C-style abstractions are used ;-). I agree that in general, there's no fundamental principle of computing which says that machine instructions have to look anything like C, so there's scope for some language/architecture combo in future to use totally different paradigms. I hear Lisp machines were all the rage for a while, but Jazelle didn't turn out so well...

Answer (score 5):

I disagree with the sentiment that you need to learn C or assembly language first. C++ and C may be similar in theory but are very different in terms of practical use. One gains little to nothing in the way of C++ idioms by using only C, and while it is good to have practical experience in multiple languages, it's an exercise in futility to specify prerequisites in language learning. I think the best way to learn the concepts of programming is to sit down with someone who understands them well and just talk about it, be that on StackOverflow, in forums, or, if you're lucky, in person.

At the end of the day, I think programming really isn't all that hard, and you may need someone to explain it right just one time to have everything click. It's all about rehashing the same simple concepts over and over to build complex and beautiful machines.

Comment: zengr isn't expressing interest in learning a language, he's expressing interest in finding out how memory management and inheritance are implemented.  Learning modern C++ idioms won't get him one step closer to that goal than he already is in Java or C#.  OTOH learning C will, or learning C idioms with a C++ compiler, will.

Comment: @Ben: "I am trying to learn C++". I answered the OP's question—the one he actually asked—to the best of my ability.

Answer (score 3):

For learning c++ I reccommend reading C++ for Java Programmers by Mark Allen Weiss. It helped me alot when moving from Java to C++ as it is very good at highlighting the differences between the languages.

Comment: Nice, crisp answer to the question "how to move from java to cpp" :)

Answer (score 2):

> But, now I feel, Java, C# makes you lame (from learning point of view) and you can develop your apps quickly but you fail to understand the basic underlying concepts of programming.

If you're trying to learn the concepts of programming, rather than machine architecture, there's not much benefit to learning C++.  I would suggest going with something different from Java all together.  A Lisp variant, perhaps.

[How To Design Programs](http://www.htdp.org/) is a pretty good book.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand the underlying concepts of programming *languages*, I would suggest a book such as John Mitchell's Concepts in Programming Languages. Follow this up by writing a few parsers/interpreters for simple languages. Another good resources is SICP, which is specific to Scheme (a LISP dialect), and available [in full here](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). Once you've learned a few languages, it doesn't take too long to pick up the syntax and semantics of a new one (the core libraries on the other hand, can take quite a while to be familiarized with).

If you want to learn about how today's computers work, I'd recommend learning C and reading books such as Tanenbaum's Modern Operating Systems. C is useful in this context mostly for reading systems level code. Implementing a (very) simple operating system can be incredibly educational. However, something as simple as implementing a basic shell (like bourne shell, except simpler) is probably a better place to start. I'd also recommend learning about how networking works specifically, since it's such an integral part of modern computer systems.

Answer (score 1):

C and C++ make **some** basic underlying programming concepts more evident, but they weren't designed by God.  I'd second the suggestion to study the actual low-level systems behind your low-level code: operating systems, compilers/runtimes (try "Essentials of Programming Languages"), and machine architecture.

P.S. In general it may be better to study C++ on its own, rather than starting with C, but for  your particular purpose -- getting more intimate with low-level, unsafe constructs such as pointers, after already learning Java -- I think it's better to start with C (and K&R) where these are front and center.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest learning assembly language first.  This will give you a very solid foundation in what is happening at a low level.  This will also help to reinforce the idea that "everything is really just an address".

Taking a class which focuses on assembly language is advisable since it will "force" you to learn it (personally, I don't think ASM is /that/ fun, but it was worthwhile [and a requirement for graduation] for me to take the class).

After you know assembly, go on to C and C++.

Have a lot of fun!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're avoiding the first mistake most people make, which is assuming the new language is the same as the old one. C++ is different and should be learned as a neww(-ish) language.
A reference I would suggest would be [C++ How to Program](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0136152503) which is used at my University for the introductory C++ classes.

After that, then look at previous Java software that you have written and seeing how you would translate them to C++. The syntax can easily be referenced from [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com). While doing this, it is important to keep in mind what all the different syntax represents, and how it changes what is going on in the software (i.e. The differences between the two languages). This has the added benefit of allowing you to see how the underlying architecture is represented for both languages (and for programming languages in general). I don't know of a good book that explains how programming languages work under the covers, or I'd recommend that.

If you are, however, interested in learning how programming works, then Assembly language would be a good place to start. [Assembly language for Intel-Based Computers](http://kipirvine.com/asm/) is what I used to learn assembly language and it was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Assembly Language.

Start with the Z-80. Then add 'x86. Then try 68000. Then the TI 320 series of DSP. You might also wish to add the Z-8. Just to see how different machines do it.

Comment: And if you want to look at a very simple multiple core (144 Cores) machine look at Green Arrays.

Comment: I don't see the point in learning more than one if you're just doing it to get background knowledge of how low-level stuff works.

Comment: Understanding the *principles* of assembly language is very helpful and not difficult (registers, 3 address codes, knowing what the instruction sets contain, etc.) will help. IMHO the effort of being able to write a program in assembly isn't worth it. You rarely ever need to go more low-level than C.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a performant C++ compiling environment such as [Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/) and go through **all** links in Bjarne Strousrup's [The C++ Programming Language](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++.html) site, beginning with C[++ Style and Technique FAQ](http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html).
If you are experimented in any other language you don't need more :-)

Comment: Why do you say Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express is a "performant C++ compiling environment"? Arn't there any better ones? I run Linux.

Comment: The debugging IDE is excellent (essential for learning), it's free and standard conforming. For Linux you will find lots of C++ IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to know more about low level programming I would recommend learning C and Assembly. C++ is much more complex than C but really doesn't give you much more insight into low level concerns. It might be interesting if you want to learn about what type of concepts and constructs a programming language can be made up of though, since C++ has a lot of them.

There is also a lower level of your VM you don't seem to know yet and which you might want to explore. To learn about the internals of Java I would recommend learning how to program the JVM in (Java) Assembly language. Jasmin (http://jasmin.sourceforge.net/) is the reference assembler/syntax for this kind of programming. Another great resource is the Java Language specification (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html) which contains a lot of Java internals. When you have learned C you can also use some lower level APIs the JVM provides (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jvmti/) that allow you to retrieve low level information about a running JVM and write interesting things like debuggers.

If you learn this stuff and do some hacking on your own you will learn how the JVM works and what the compiler actually puts into your class files. It's also very likely that you discover some new things about the Java programming language itself you didn't know before even if you think you know everything about it.

You can also program the .Net VM in assembly by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with C, but not as a necessary preamble for learning C++. Rather, for learning C. In other words, while you learn C put your efforts into learning the language, feeling the philosophy of the language and focusing on letting it sip into your skin. Be a good C programmer and you will be a good programmer, period. Not just a good C++ programmer -- this has nothing to do with learning C -- but a good programmer.

There's another reason for learning C first. It's easier than C++, much easier than C++, and it bridges well to C++ (in contrast to Java, which doesn't in all aspects but the most superficial object-oriented ones). I'm not talking about the syntax similarities: I'm talking about low-level programming. I'm talking about the concepts of pointers, which exist as themselves and in the form of iterators in C++. You can pass around functions in C, and you can pass around function objects in C++. C is fast to learn, and it will warm you up very effectively.

Learning C will also eliminate the fear of free functions some pure OO programmers tend to have. C++ is a hybrid language, and C truly is a subset of C++, not just by syntax but by philosophy as well.

Start by getting yourself the K&R book and drinking it through. You won't regret this.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you start off with, my suggestion would be dump the full fledged IDE's. Use good text editors (vim/emacs)

The learning curve is better when using text editors since everything needs to be written on your own. No prompts and no pre-written code.

You have all  the best answers above, in anycase. :)

- Ivar

Comment: Good idea, learn emacs or vim and you wont bother learning cpp at all- theres just no more spare time :P I still think that good software is easy and intuitive to use, even for beginners.

Comment: if you notice, he did mention that he has all the time in the world...IDEs are good definitely, no doubt, to increase your productivity and all...but in order to learn something basic...i would definitely suggest to start from basic... - Ivar

Answer (score 0):

Learn C and C++ at the same time, I'm talking from experience here. Very often I come across code that mixes C and C++, so it's better to know both and their differences. Pick up K&R for C (understand pointers, header files and manual memory allocation and cleaning...which are not used by Java!) and any decent C++ beginner book (I picked Prata, but whatever you are more comfortable with). Practice the same examples doing versions of C, C++ in a sequential fashion, object-oriented (OO) fashion, generic/template fashion etc. C++ has a larger standard library than C: templates, STL containers (no need for pointers, but you can do pointer fine tuning writing your own container), threads (since C++11). You can always use C if you have no choice (or Boost libraries), any C++ compiler will allow it.

If you come from Java you should already know OO concepts for C++, and, perhaps, some generic programming as in C++ templates. C++ is mistakenly regarded as an OO language, but it's more than that. BTW, objects are a dynamic concept (runtime), whereas templates are static (compilation time), so learn the language CONCEPTS, not just the syntax! Once you learn the concepts read Stroustrup's book (he created C++) to learn his philosophy for the best design rules for C++ code.

Learn the latest C++ standard (C++11) as it adds many new things to the language (auto, nullptr, threads, lambda functions, new containers, etc.). Last but not least, please use Doxygen in C/C++ the same way you used Javadoc....there is nothing worse than undocumented, unreadable code no matter what language you're using.

Answer (score -2):

Learn Forth. It has better Objects. And it is a virtual machine. Unless you want a real machine see Green Arrays or Sandpiper/John Rible for that.

Free threaded interpreted versions are all over the 'net. For practice. When you understand it write your own Direct Threaded version. Or see Forth Inc and buy one for your machine or use their free windows version.

Java is a Forth/C hybrid so if you want to go Java you will have some of the stuff under your belt.

Education:

Starting Forth - Brodie
Thinking Forth - Brodie

The second is excellent for any language because it is the best book on factoring I know. Free Versions of both on the net.

If you want to do a hardware/FPGA Forth Stack Machines: The New Wave by Koopman

All the above books are free on the 'net.

Comment: What has FORTH got to do with either Java or C++? Did you even attempt to read the question before you posted this answer?

Comment: He said he *already* knows Java, and wants to get a lower-level perspective on programming.  I don't see how another language with a virtual machine will accomplish that.

Comment: Forth and JVM are both stack based machine does not mean their have any thing in common in programming paradigm and syntax. Their totally different. Learning Forth has nothing to do with learning C++.